# Change ImageIcon in JLabel using Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton, imageicon

I have two classes: logic and the `JFrame`. In frame I have a `JLabel` and a `JButton`, and I would like to:

When this button is clicked, the `ImageIcon` in the label changes after a determined time using a Swing `Timer`, like if it is flashing. To do it I loaded two images with different brightness (`img1b` and `img1`). I tried to make the timer change the image twice with different delays, but I was unsuccessful. I also put a listener in the button and implemented the `actionPerformed` as below:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(btnImg1)) {
        logic.piscaImagen(img1, lblImg1);
        logic.piscaImagen(img1b, lblImg1);
```

In logic class:

```
public void piscaImagen(ImageIcon img, JLabel lbl) {

        Timer timer = new Timer(1250, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if(lbl.getIcon() != img){
                    lbl.setIcon(img);
            }
        }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
}
```

But when I run it nothing changes in the `logic.piscaImagen`. Any tips?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - I'd recommend to do this in stages.  1) Show both images in 2 labels in the frame.  2) Establish a repeating timer during the initialization of the GUI to change the images in a **single** label. 3) Set repeating false (with a long delay) and check it one more time. 4) Shorten the delay and attempt it from a button action on click (instead of at startup).

Answer (score 1):

```
logic.piscaImagen(img1, lblImg1);
logic.piscaImagen(img1b, lblImg1);
```

It looks to me like you are starting two Timers. So the first Timer fires and it changes the image, then the second timer fires and it restores the image so basically you only see the first image.

All you need is one Timer. Each time the Timer fires you change the image. So the basic code in your Timer would be:

```
if (lbl.getIcon() == img1)
    lbl.setIcon(img1b);
else
    lbl.setIcon(img1);
```

Or for a more flexible solution you can use the [Animated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/).

The `Animated Icon` will allow you to specify a List of Icons to display. Then when the Timer fires the next Icon in the List is displayed. You can set the `Animated Icon` for continuous display or you can control the number of cycles.

Comment: As a side-question, I've had a quick look at your Animated Icon - is there any real disadvantage to setting up the animation any other way (i.e. a `Runnable` class flipping every X milliseconds)? Assuming a GUI-driven application, and not a complex 2D-rendered scene, of course.

Comment: Exactly, what I want is to change an image, and then restore it but after a certain delay (2000ms), in paper is a easy task but i cant make it work.

Comment: @Gorbles, Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information. Swing timer code executes on the EDT a Thread Runnable does not.

Comment: @user3111762, and you have been given advice on how to solve the problem. You need to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate your problem. That is create a frame with a JLabel and a Swing Timer. It should take about 20 lines of code. Chances are the code will work, but if not, then you have simple code to post of the forum. We can't guess what you are doing wrong based on the information provided.

Comment: Ahh, I understand those limitations @camickr. The implementation in my case ensures components aren't accessed across threads (the object once created is left to run the `paintComponent` loop until the frame is killed) but I'll definitely bear that in mind when I revise the code. Derail finished!

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: answer inaccurate, `repaint()` not necessary - see comments.

---

You're missing the `repaint()` call that tells the program it needs to update the display.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(lbl.getIcon() != img){ 
        lbl.setIcon(img);
        lbl.repaint();
    }
}
```

(your `if` statement was also missing a closing brace, unsure what impact that would have / if it was a typo)

Comment: You don't need the repaint(). When you change a property of a Swing component, the component invokes `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on itself to make sure it is repainted.

Comment: Specifically only when changing a property then? Adding / removing components doesn't trigger this, for example. I swear I've had issues with `repaint` being required before, but I've moved mainly to `paintComponent` overrides these days.

Comment: When adding/removing components from a panel you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the panel to invoke the layout manager (otherwise the newly added component will have a size of 0). Typically the panel will then repaint itself but I always add `repaint()` just to make sure. ` but I've moved mainly to paintComponent overrides these days` - if you are doing custom painting then you need the repaint, but again the better design is to have a setter method on the properties of you class and then the setter method invokes the revalidate() and repaint, not the application code.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it still doesnt work, i cant see the imagens changing. gonna edit with more code =/ EDIT: Now I see a fast change between the logic.piscaImagen(img1, lblImg1) and logic.piscaImagen(img1b, lblImg1), like a flash, but i need it to be slower.